# Include my post with followers post in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can include my post with the followers' post

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logged_in_user = request.user
    video = Video.objects.filter(
        author__follow__in=[logged_in_user.id]
    ).order_by('-created_date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to express a disjunction:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    video = Video.objects.filter(
        Q(author__follow=request.user) | Q(author=request.user)
    ).order_by('-created_date')
```